# hide "groups" based on formulae In Crystalreports ..?/

Tags: crystal-reports

am doing a report for showing catogory-sub-category wise sales report.

i made to group headers with category and sub-category

What i want to do is.. Hide subcategory(Group-Header) --> if user didn't specify or select any subcategory.

..??

Comment: http://tel2.smude.edu.in/images/Assignment/Spring-Drive-Assignment-2012/INFORMATION%20TECHOLOGY/MCA-Revised-Spring_Feb_2012/MC0086-Spring%20Drive%20Assignment-2012.pdf

Comment: http://tel2.smude.edu.in/images/Assignment/Spring-Drive-Assignment-2012/INFORMATION%20TECHOLOGY/MCA-Revised-Spring_Feb_2012/MC0087-Spring%20Drive%20Assignment-2012.pdf

Comment: http://tel2.smude.edu.in/images/Assignment/Spring-Drive-Assignment-2012/INFORMATION%20TECHOLOGY/MCA-Revised-Spring_Feb_2012/MC0088-Spring%20Drive%20Assignment-2012.pdf

Comment: http://madteam.co/forum/tutorials/tutorial-to-install-android-sdk-in-windows-7-32-bit/

Comment: <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblTemplate" CssClass="asptbllinks">  
                   
            <asp:TableRow ID="PageAction_List" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableCell>

Comment: function ShowHide(flag) {
        if (flag == "ADD_DETAILS") {
            $("[id$=SEC_ActionPanel]").hide();
            $("[id$=State_Entry]").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("[id$=State_Entry]").show();
            $("[id$=SEC_ActionPanel]").show();
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "ShowErrorMsg", "ShowErrorMessage('" + litErrorMsg.Text + "');", true);

Comment: #1A87B0, #7EC6E0, Border- #9DD0E3,text- #FFFFFF

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Comment: Comments(1), Likes(2), Votes count(2), Login(1), User Profile(1), View post and Edit post(1)(View post form & Edit post form)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594/css-not-being-applied-on-non-authenticated-asp-net-page

Comment: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard

Comment: http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Notification-Indian-Navy-SSC-Officer-Posts.pdf

Comment: Check this out For preps;

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1183-abstract-class.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239939/Csharp-Tweaks-Why-to-use-the-sealed-keyword-on-cla.aspx
http://scienceray.com/biology/inheritance-and-its-types/
http://www.programcall.com/20/csnet/types-of-inheritance-in-csnet.aspx
http://www.programcall.com/27/csnet/abstract-classes-and-abstract-methods-in-csnet.aspx

Comment: http://www.programcall.com/25/csnet/method-overriding-in-csnet.aspx
http://www.programcall.com/26/csnet/virtual-methods-in-csnet-with-example.aspx
http://www.rapidprogramming.com/questions-answers/What-are-the-new-features-of-C-Sharp-4-0--724
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/06/c-40-features.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/skumaar_mca/garbage-collection-in-net-framework/
http://www.programcall.com/22/csnet/sealed-class-and-sealed-method-in-csnet.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52857/ASP-NET-Page-Life-Cycle
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiru_ji/1DotnetAssemblies02212007050300AM/1DotnetAssemblies.aspx
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/assemblies/article.php/c11905/Assemblies-in-NET.htm
http://www.techbubbles.com/wcf/wcf-vs-aspnet-web-services/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702732.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to conditionally suppress your group header based on the value of the parameter. To do this:

1. Select the Section Expert... option from the Report menu.
2. Select the subcategory Group Header section in the Section Exprt dialog.
3. Click on the formula button for the Suppress (No Drill-Down) option.
4. Enter the formula `IsNull ({?subcategory})` and click `Save and close`.
5. Click OK at the bottom of the Section Expert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
 .no-wrapper{ float:left;}
 .no-wrapper  a#triangleUP{height:30px;}
  #triangleDWN {height:30px;}
     a#triangleUP
      {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 20px;
        border-color: transparent  transparent  #7EC6E0  transparent;
       display:block;
      }
     a#triangleDWN
      {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 20px;
        border-color: #7EC6E0  transparent  transparent  transparent;
       display:block;
      }
span.center{ text-align:center; display:block;font-size:24px;}
     a#triangleDWN:hover{border-color: #1A87B0  transparent  transparent  transparent;}
     a#triangleUP:hover{border-color: transparent  transparent  #1A87B0  transparent;}
      a{text-decoration:NONE;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="no-wrapper">
<a id="triangleUP" href="#">&nbsp</a>
      <span class="center">1</span>
  <a id="triangleDWN"  href="#">&nbsp</a>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```