# Azure Sample Website Graphics not working

Tags: asp.net, azure

I've uploaded a simple Azure website (am testing out authentication) and have found this:

http://mateerweb.cloudapp.net/  (live for next 12 hours or so!)

[image]

Its supposed to look like this:
[image]

**Problem:** How to get the live version looking like the test one on every deploy.  After a recompile sometimes it works..

Comment: I wanna -1 you so bad for using IE.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594/css-not-being-applied-on-non-authenticated-asp-net-page

Comment: Cheers Shawn and Craig... so, whats wrong with IE :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its failing the retrieve the css file. Your permissions is blocking access to the css. It requires login to get the css file.

You need to allow direct access to your css as a content.